# Simplified Faulhaber's Formula

Tags: sequences-and-series

While I was trying to devise formulas for $\sum_{k=1}^n k^2$ and $\sum_{k=1}^n k^3$ (I know their explicit formulas, I wanted to proof that on my own) I came up with a formula that computes formulas for (pTH) power sum ($1^p+2^p+3^p+...+n^p$),  and during the past few days I wanted to publish my formula and I found my formula already exists (which is Faulhaber's formula)
mine is simplified formula, but it works only if $power \geqslant 2$, and you should know formulas for 1 to (p-1) to devise (p) formula.

So I'm asking you what to do, should publish it or develop it then publish, or just keep it to my self?

Comment: I guess it would be helpful to actual state your results so others can assess this properly.

Comment: you mean to write the formula?

Comment: Yes. In that way one can judge if this is a new result or just a special case which follows easily from the known formula.

Comment: @Viktor I would like to, but I got my formula stolen?I know it's not that important, but I don't want someone to famous because of me in a way I don't want

Answer (score 3):

I don't know exactly what you are referring to but we do have that
$$1^k+2^k+\cdots+n^k$$
$$=\frac1{k+1}\left((n+1)^{k+1}-1-\sum_{p=0}^{k-1}\binom{k+1}{p}(1^p+2^p+\cdots+n^p)\right)$$
which follows from the telescoping sum on [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula) Wikipedia page.